# Relative Layout facing Circular Dependencies in android

Tags: android, xml, circular-dependency

This is my logcat

```
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1691)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:373)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1226)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:326)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-12 01:51:47.855: E/AndroidRuntime(4707):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Login" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/passwordlogin"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/passwordlogin"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/useridlogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/passwordlogin"
            android:layout_below="@id/textViewLogin"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/useridlogin"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/userid"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordlogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textViewPassword"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/registerlauncher"
            android:layout_below="@id/passwordlogin"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/button_login" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newuser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/newuser" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/registerlauncher"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textViewLogin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/button_register" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/useridlogin"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_main"
            android:src="@drawable/pos_malaysia" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I wonder why my other xml file works fine, but this activity_login.xml failed to display in Graphical Layout. The error said **Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout**

Comment: make sure that your above/below controls don't reference each other (control1 above control2 and control2 below control1), Also, don't use **@+id** in references, since this CREATES new ids (and could cause circular refs). use **@+id** only when defining NEW ids

Comment: @DerGolem I found out that above/below keywords and thanks for pointing out also the @+id. I forgot to delete that Thanks you helps

Comment: @DerGolem no new id is created if it exists although using `@id` is not a problem

Comment: I thought that `@+id` is for creating an id and `@id` for referencing.

Comment: OK, I think I missed this part `"The plus symbol, +, indicates that this is a new resource ID and the aapt tool will create a new resource integer in the R.java class, if it doesn't already exist."`

Comment: @Raghunandan so @+id is also means creating and also referencing at the same time. I just want to understand more clearly.

Comment: @Jiazzyuser `@+id` creates a new resource id. You can check and look @ R.java as soon as you add a resource id. While referencing you can have `@+id` or `@id` Supppose you have 2 textviews. First you have textview 1 but you need to place textview 1 above textview2. textview2 still does not have id then you can use `android:layout_above= @+id/textView2`

Comment: @Jiazzyuser easier to explain if i post an example

Comment: @Raghunandan I got your meaning already. Thanks Raghunandan, you have been helped me a lot in Android coding and concept.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/passwordlogin"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: It did help solve the problem though, it just that I don't want **textViewLogin** to be `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`